# Sending strings via java.nio channels not working correctly

Tags: java, sockets, io, nio

This is what I've tried:

Server:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class JavaApplication12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    ServerSocketChannel s = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    s.configureBlocking(true);
    s.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(1024));
    CharBuffer c = CharBuffer.wrap("Hello from server!");
    System.out.println("writing " + c);
    ByteBuffer b = charset.encode(c);
    SocketChannel sc = s.accept();
    sc.configureBlocking(true);
    b.flip();
    int a = sc.write(b);
    sc.close();
    s.close();
    System.out.println("wrote " + a);
}
}
```

Client:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class JavaApplication11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1024));
    sc.configureBlocking(true);
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
    b.flip();
    int a = sc.read(b);
    sc.close();
    b.flip();
    CharBuffer c = charset.decode(b);
    c.flip();
    System.out.println("Got " + c);
    System.out.println("read " + a );
}
}
```

The other side seems to just get a very long and empty string, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**Update**: I've updated my code, and found that the server is writing 0 bytes. There are bytes to write, so why isn't `sc.write()` writing anything?

**Update 2**: With Vishal's help we finally have a working solution:

Server:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
ServerSocketChannel s = ServerSocketChannel.open();
s.configureBlocking(true);
s.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(1024));
CharBuffer c = CharBuffer.wrap("Hello from server!");
ByteBuffer b = charset.encode(c);
SocketChannel sc = s.accept();
sc.configureBlocking(true);
b.compact();
b.flip();
int a = sc.write(b);
sc.close();
s.close();
System.out.println("wrote " + a);
```

Client:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1024));
sc.configureBlocking(true);
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
int a = sc.read(b);
sc.close();
b.flip();
CharBuffer c = charset.decode(b);
System.out.println("Got " + c);
```

Comment: Why are you using `b.flip()` on server side before sending the data to client? And also at client side before reading the data...?

Comment: My understanding is when you make a `ByteBuffer` or any other kind of `Buffer` they start out in write mode, so you have to flip them to put them in read mode. Otherwise I don't understand this whole thing properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[Buffer.flip()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip%28%29)** method **switches a Buffer from writing
>   mode to reading mode**. Calling `flip()` sets the ***position*** back to 0, and
>   sets the ***limit*** to where position just was. 
>   i.e the ***position*** now marks the reading position, and ***limit***
>   marks how many bytes, chars etc. were written into the buffer - the
>   limit of how many bytes, chars etc. that can be read

If you see at documentation of `Buffer.flip()` it states that:

> After a sequence of channel-read or **`put` operations**, invoke this method
>   to prepare for a sequence of channel-write or relative get operations.

And further is states that:

> This method is often used in conjunction with the `compact` method when
>   transferring data from one place to another.

In your case , `put` operation is not used for `ByteBuffer`  creation. So you would have to call `compact` method before the flip is called.

`ByteBuffer's`  [**compact()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#compact%28%29) method stays that:

> The bytes between the buffer's current position and its limit, if any,
>   are copied to the beginning of the buffer. That is, the byte at index
>   p = position() is copied to index zero, the byte at index p + 1 is
>   copied to index one, and so forth until the byte at index limit() - 1
>   is copied to index n = limit() - 1 - p. The buffer's position is then
>   set to n+1 and its limit is set to its capacity. The mark, if defined,
>   is discarded.
>
> **The buffer's position is set to the number of bytes copied, rather
>   than to zero, so that an invocation of this method can be followed
>   immediately by an invocation of another relative put method.**
>   *Invoke this method after writing data from a buffer in case the write was incomplete.*

In your code at server side Before `flip()` is called the position was itself 0 . So to set the `position` to number bytes written to `b` You would have to call `compact()` method before `b.flip()` is called so that the `b.flip()` sets the `limit` to the previous `position` which is the number of bytes wrote to `ByteBuffer` , and set the `position` to `0`.

Consequently Your Server Code should be like this:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class JavaApplication12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    ServerSocketChannel s = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    s.configureBlocking(true);
    s.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(1024));

    CharBuffer c = CharBuffer.wrap("Hello from server!");
    System.out.println("writing " + c);
    ByteBuffer b = charset.encode(c);
    System.out.println(new String(b.array()));
    SocketChannel sc = s.accept();
    //sc.configureBlocking(true);
    b.compact();
    System.out.println(b.capacity() + " "+ b.position() + " " + b.limit());
    b.flip();
    System.out.println(b.capacity() + " "+ b.position() + " " + b.limit());
    int a = 0;
    while (b.hasRemaining())
    {
        a += sc.write(b);
    }

    sc.close();
    s.close();
    System.out.println("wrote " + a);
    }
}
```

LikeWise , At client side your code should be like this:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class JavaApplication11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1024));
    sc.configureBlocking(true);
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
    //b.flip();//Don't flip the ByteBuffer here because it sets the position to 0 and limit to 0 also. Hence no read.
    int a = sc.read(b);
    sc.close();
    b.flip();//sets the Position to 0 and limit to the number of bytes to be read.
    CharBuffer c = charset.decode(b);
    //c.flip();//Don't flip the ChharBuffer. Because it is setting the position to zero and limit to previous position i.e zero
    System.out.println("Got " + c);
    System.out.println("read " + a );
    }
}
```

> **Note**:I have put comment on lines where you made mistakes.

Comment: Won't printing it in that way give me ASCII codes instead of the actual letters themselves? Thanks for that socket bit, I'll definitely try that when I get home from work.

Comment: The `SocketChannel` is not writing data to the buffer, it's reading data from the buffer and writing it to the socket.

Comment: Okay, adding `compact()` on the server side actually writes stuff now, and after getting rid of the `flip()` on the client side it actually reads 18 bytes of data so there's definite progress. Now I just need to get it to decode properly because it's still outputting a big blank line.

Comment: @LoganDam: Where is it outputting a big blank line??? It is working fine at my side..

Comment: Nothing, it's working fine now. I said in the OP that I have a working solution now.

Comment: ahh ok ok..Perhaps i read you message about "big blank line" much later ...! Glad to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to flip() the buffer between the read() and the decode().

Comment: The buffer itself contains nothing right after reading anyway, so even flipping won't help. It just seems the data gets lost somewhere along the way.